# How to prove this $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}$ is a probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am learning the change of measure recently, and the textbook defines a probability measure $\tilde{\mathbb{P}} $ in this following way:

> Let (Ω, $\mathbb{F} $, $\mathbb{P} $) be a probability space. Let $f $ be a nonnegative random variable with $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[f]=1 $. For any set $A \in \mathbb{F} $, define the quantity
>
> $\qquad \qquad \tilde{\mathbb{P}}(A) = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\mathbb{1}_Af]= \int_Af(ω)d\mathbb{P}(ω) $

Then it states this $\tilde{\mathbb{P}} $ is a probability measure without any explanations.

I want to prove this is a probability measure. I recalled the definition of a probability measure:

> A probability measure is a map $\mathbb{P}:\mathbb{F} \to [0,1] $ such that
>
> 1. For countable ${A_n} $ such that $A_n \cap A_m = \phi $ for $n \ne m $, $\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_nA_n)=\sum_n\mathbb{P}(A_n)$.
> 2. $\mathbb{P}(\phi)=0 $ and $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=1 $.

Here, the second definition is easy to prove. Here is the proof:

The indicator $\mathbb{1}_{\phi}=0$, $\mathbb{1}_{\Omega}=1$

$\qquad \tilde{\mathbb{P}}(\phi)= \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\mathbb{1}_\phi f]= 0, \quad \tilde{\mathbb{P}}(\Omega)= \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\mathbb{1}_\Omega f]= 1$.

However my question is, how to prove the first definition? Or there is other ways to prove this is a probability measure using definitions?

Many thanks.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: It’s the lecture note posted by my professor. However I’m not sure the original textbook.

Comment: the integral respects the condition 1, in fact

Comment: Can you give some more details? I don’t really get what you mean by “the integral respects the condition 1”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) can be proved in a straightforward manner by just plugging things in. Assume you have a countable family of pairwise disjoint sets $A_i$. Just use the fact (or prove) that for such a family $1_{\cup_i A_i}(\omega)=\sum_i 1_{A_i}(\omega)$

Comment: Where does this fact come from? I can understand it intuitively but is this troublesome to prove?

Comment: To prove it, invoke the definition of an indicator function on a set $B$. It's 1 iff $\omega\in B$. So just consider the set of $\omega$ that make the left side equal to 0,1, and then verify that is the same set on the right. Don't forget that $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint, so that any $\omega$ either belongs to exactly one $A_i$ or none.